# Token Symbol doesn't change in extend-parachain-template

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, substrate-node

I have changed properties of token [here github repo](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/xcav-praachain/blob/4c2b177325037c00cd28dac10e79c02fe6a03431/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L76), but symbol of token doesn't change while running node in dev mode `./target/release/parachain-template-node --dev`. Is this because of parachain?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed adding those properties [here](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/xcav-praachain/blob/4c2b177325037c00cd28dac10e79c02fe6a03431/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L122) like you did it [here](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/xcav-praachain/blob/4c2b177325037c00cd28dac10e79c02fe6a03431/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L183)